# why am I getting "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or thing credential is wrong"?

Tags: here-api

Trying to generate a token for a device, getting ""Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or thing credential is wrong"
not sure what I am doing incorrectly

sending a POST request with the headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="ac85020f-c352-4ac9-853e-4b64f3645463", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_timestamp="1558262091", oauth_nonce="LIIBLApk88", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="e894d7545b903c16723c1051305828efc52623da534197a50d782f82b9f0149c"

the oauth signature is HMAC-SHA256 of: POST&https%3A%2F%2Ftracking.api.here.com%2Fv2%2Ftoken&oauth_consumer_key%3Dac85020f-c352-4ac9-853e-4b64f3645463%26oauth_nonce%3DLIIBLApk5%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1558260025%26oauth_version%3D1.0

signed with: {Device secret}&

and getting:
{
    "code": 401,
    "id": "624b4eb2-7838-450d-8c5c-363c3df4f308",
    "message": "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or thing credential is wrong.",
    "error": "*Timestamp wrong*\n\nWhen the request timestamp has a more than 10 second difference from the\nserver time, the `x-here-timestamp` header with the current server\ntimestamp is added to the response.\n\n*Incorrect Signature*\n\nIf the OAuth signature is incorrect, the response will be a 401 but\n*without* the `x-here-timestamp` field.\n"
}

and the timpestamp isn't wrong

Comment: Which service exactly did you try to call via POST? Can you provide this too?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue right now. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a bit in your oauth signature. I had the same issue. it should look like

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Faccount.api.here.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&grant_type%3Dclient_credentials%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26oauth_nonce%3D5e5c338b14198%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1583100811%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

you are missing the grant_type%3Dclient_credentials just after the 'token&'

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar situation, the & inbetween Host and params (and after POST as well) needs to be excluded from URLEncoding:

```
'POST&' + encodeURIComponent('https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token') + '&' + encodeURIComponent(paramString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an access key and signature, you can request a token using the token REST API. A typical request includes these elements:

**URL** https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token

**HTTP Header**

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key="",
oauth_nonce="",
oauth_signature="",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
oauth_timestamp="",
oauth_version="1.0"

**Request Body**

The request body must contain:
grant_type=client_credentials

**Note: The value for grant_type must always be client_credentials.**

Answer (score 0):

- I am getting same issue. I found URL mismatch at the time of header
  signature generation and api calling URL. So i think you missed or
  add some something like space or other little thing you need to
  recheck your code again and verify it carefully. I am sure it works
  for you.